# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment fullscreen button forces orientation change and does not enter fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-youtube-api

i am creating `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`. Playing in portrait mode works just fine. As soon as i click the fullscreen button of the player it forces an orientation change and recreates the activity i am in (the video stops playing and the fragment is recreated).

this is how i create the fragment:

```
fragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
fragment.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
```

The only similar thing on StackOverflow I could find was this question: [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment starts duplicate Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714291/youtubeplayersupportfragment-starts-duplicate-activity)

This guy has the same problem but no answer so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was i did't call super.onSaveInstanceState(b) on my own onSaveInstanceState...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and apparently it's defined behaviour. You can disable it like this (for example in onInitializationSucces):

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean success) {
    player.setFullscreenControlFlags(0);
```

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION).

Comment: Thanks @saragis... really helped