# YoutubeSupportFragment into Fullscreen(Landscape) without affecting the default orientation(Portrait)

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

In my YouTubePlayerSupportFragment, onInitializationSuccess I set the YouTube player to fullscreen which makes my whole app goes into Landscape orientation, so is there a way to overcome it? 
My try was to was to override onConfigurationChanged inside The youtubeFragment and not call super.onConfigurationChanged.
Also I tried adding

> ```
>         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
> ```

inside the Manifest file but didn't work out either

Comment: So you want the player to be fullscreen portrait orientation?

Comment: No I want it landscape orientation(which I can do by setting the fullscreen flag), without having effect on the app orientation itself. Setting the fullscreen flag into true, makes my whole activity load again in the landscape orientation

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105140/youtubeplayersupportfragment-fullscreen-button-forces-orientation-change-and-doe) can help you out.